# Can I use matrix algebra to solve this probability?

Tags: probability

From another discussion forum:

One throws dice $n$ times. What is the probability that during $n-1$ times one has got five different values and gets the missing sixth value on his last throw?

I wondered whether linear algebra is suitable for that. Namely, can we make a matrix $P$ to describe probabilities and then compute $P^{n-1}\cdot v$ and $P^n\cdot v$ where $v$ is the vector of initial conditions? The problem is that I have no idea how to compute $P^n$ symbolically.

Comment: Wouldn't $A_3$ be {$2$}?

Comment: The probability for 6 would be $\frac{j}{n}$, $j =$ number of 6's in $A_i$

Comment: I tried to explain it without symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Without Matrix Algebra:

It should be $\displaystyle \frac{6 \times 5\times ... total~n+1 ~terms...\times 5 \times 1}{6\times...total ~n ~terms ... \times 6} = \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-1}$

Regarding using matrix algebra, I can't even figure out what the initial vector should be..